# Running .glsl in VS code

Tags: graphics, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am trying to run a GLSL file (.glsl extension) in VS code but it's not working. I have installed and enabled VS code extensions like WebGL GLSL editor, Shader languages support for VS Code, GLSL canvas. But when I run the code it's not working. I have used extensions like .frag, .glsl, but it's not working. When I run it, I'm getting the following error, and a black screen on canvas.

`Load error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')"`

Here's the code I have tried. This works on the [twigl.app](https://twigl.app?ol=true&ss=-NZvBZBTjKWHAZ_HN2l1) but it's not compiling in VS code. What should I do?

```
precision highp float;
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform float time;

void main() {
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;

    // Generate rapid movement effect
    float speed = 5.0;
    vec2 offset = vec2(
        cos(time * speed),
        sin(time * speed)
    );

    // Generate trippy color effect
    vec3 color = vec3(
        sin(time * 1.0 + uv.x * 10.0) * cos(uv.y * 10.0),
        cos(time * 1.5 + uv.y * 5.0) * sin(uv.x * 10.0),
        cos(time * 2.0) * sin(uv.x * uv.y * 20.0)
    );

    // Apply color palette
    vec3 lavender = vec3(0.8, 0.6, 1.0);
    vec3 orange = vec3(1.0, 0.6, 0.2);
    vec3 pastelPink = vec3(1.0, 0.7, 0.8);
    vec3 pastelYellow = vec3(1.0, 0.9, 0.4);
    vec3 lightBlue = vec3(0.6, 0.8, 1.0);

    color = mix(color, lavender, 0.1);
    color = mix(color, orange, 0.2);
    color = mix(color, pastelPink, 0.3);
    color = mix(color, pastelYellow, 0.4);
    color = mix(color, lightBlue, 0.5);

    // Apply movement offset
    uv += offset * 0.03;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the wrong uniform names. According to [glsl-canvas's uniform description](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=circledev.glsl-canvas#uniforms), you should use `u_resolution` and `u_time` instead of just `resolution` and `time`.

Also, I think there is a bit of confusion with the extensions. glsl-canvas is the one that runs the code and renders the result onto the screen, while WebGL GLSL Editor (I'm the developer of this one), and Shader languages support for VS Code can't run the code, they just provide language features, like syntax highlight, code completion, etc.